# Best Option for Class Structure for Duplicate Pdf Report Generation - Laravel

Tags: laravel

In a Laravel project, I have multiple instances of a script that generates a report for a single object and its related child objects.

```
$pdf = PDF::loadView('payments.reports.stripe-payouts-report', compact('payments','report','arrival_date'))->setOption('header-center', 'Stripe Payout Report - Expected Arrival Date: - '.$arrival_date)->setOption("footer-center", "Page [page] of [topage]")->setOption('footer-right', 'Generated on: '.\Carbon\Carbon::now())->setOption('footer-font-size', 8)->setOption('header-font-size', 8);
$pdf->setPaper('letter');
$pdf->setOption('enable-javascript', true);
$pdf->setOption('javascript-delay', 1000);
$pdf->setOption('no-stop-slow-scripts', true);
$pdf->setOption('enable-smart-shrinking', true);
$pdf->setOrientation('landscape');
return $pdf->download();
```

Now my question is, if this has multiple instances, what would be the best way of preparing this? A class of its own, since I have more reports that are similar but not exactly the same? And if so, how stored in the folder structure? Would it be in a Report Folder with a class associated with it?

I'd appreciate any and all help to make sure this makes as much sense structure wise, because I'm at a loss as to the best way to handle this.

Thanks!

Comment: Are you attempting to make a service?

Comment: Can you please clarify what you mean by "preparing"? Do you have multiple instances of the `$pdf` object that need to be returned, multiple duplicate pdf files that need to be stored in your folder?